# Filtering an array with a possible undefined value in prisma

Tags: node.js, graphql, nestjs, prisma

]I'm currently using a GraphQL Api which I then use a resolver to fetch the data from the DB.

this is my graphql resolver

```
  async getVideoPosts(
    @Args({ name: 'keywords', type: () => [String], nullable: true }) keywords: string[]): Promise<VideoPost[]> {
    const findVideoQuery = await this.prismaService.videoPost.findMany({
      where: { keywords: {hasSome: keywords}}
    })
```

And my usecase is this:
I'm trying to filter an array of videos, using keywords array, that if they exist, it will fetch all the records that contain some of the values (using hasSome filter) however, if I get undefined from graphql, it'll return all the records and not filter at all.
For some reason, if prisma gets undefined in the array filter it returns an error.
I've looked at the docs and it says that whenever a filter option gets undefined, it's as if it wasn't written and it'll ignore it.

This is what im getting when the keywords graphql argument is undefined:

```
Argument where.keywords of type StringNullableListFilter needs at least one argument. Available args are listed in green.
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass `undefined` or `null` to `hasSome`. You will need to do some validation on `keywords` before you pass it.

I would be curious to read the docs you referenced.

Comment: The docs I read were here:
https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/null-and-undefined#the-effect-of-null-and-undefined-on-conditionals